# Quels sont les dialectes français?

Tags: régionalismes, dialectes

Lors de nos dernières vacances en Bretagne, ma compagne, qui est Allemande, me demande si le breton est un dialecte français. Je lui réponds que non, c'est une langue en elle-même, ce que je définirais comme langue régionale. Elle n'a pas été convaincue, mais je suis sûr que j'ai raison. (J'ai raison, n'est-ce pas ?)

Anecdote à part, cela a entraîné une conversation sur les dialectes français, et je me suis rendu compte que je séchais pas mal sur le sujet.

Mes questions sont donc les suivantes :

- Où met-on la barrière entre un dialecte français et une langue régionale ?
- Et quels sont les dialectes reconnus à l'échelle nationale ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Un dialecte n'est pas obligatoirement lié au territoire, le terme peut s'appliquer à une façon de parler d'un groupe de gens liés par leur métier, leurs aspirations, etc.

Même si le terme de dialecte est parfois employé pour désigner les langues régionales ce n'est pas le terme qu'emploient les linguistes et les politiques qui parlent de langues régionales, et les langues régionales, comme le français et d'autres langues, font partie des langues de France.

Sur le site de la [DGLFLF](http://www.dglflf.culture.gouv.fr/) (délégation générale à la langue française et aux langues de France) il y a une 
[rubrique](http://www.dglflf.culture.gouv.fr/lgfrance/lgfrance.htm) consacrée aux langues de France avec des définitions, des cartes et des considérations politiques.

Sur le site [Corpus de la parole](http://corpusdelaparole.in2p3.fr) on trouve des liens vers [toutes les langues régionales](http://corpusdelaparole.in2p3.fr/spip.php?rubrique10)  de France ainsi que vers les langues de France.

En ce moment sur [Canal Académie](http://www.canalacademie.com) il y a une série d'émissions proposée par la linguistique Henriette Walter sur [les langues régionales de France](http://www.canalacademie.com/idr202-Les-langues-regionales-de-France-.html). 
 Seules les 5 dernières émissions de la série sont en libre écoute (->sans abonnement).
La première émission de la série s'appelle justement « Les langues régionales de France : langue, dialecte et patois ».

**Édition** :

Je devrais être plus nuancée, plus précise.
On appelle  couramment une variante d'une langue régionale un *dialecte* ou *parler*.
Par exemple : le provençal est un dialecte occitan ; le gallo et le picard sont des dialectes de langue d'oïl.

Pour en revenir à la Bretagne,  sais-tu si ce que vous avez entendu est du [breton](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breton), langue d'origine celtique parlée dans l'ouest de la Bretagne, ou du [gallo](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallo), qui est une variante/ un dialecte de la langue d'oïl parlée à l'est de la Bretagne ?

Comment: +1 pour cette carte http://www.dglflf.culture.gouv.fr/ressources/cartes/langues_regionales.pdf

Comment: Étant donné qu'on était dans le Finistère, je suis quasiment sur que c'était du breton.

Comment: Le lien ne fonctionne plus, [voici](https://web.archive.org/web/20131014042034/http://www.dglflf.culture.gouv.fr/ressources/cartes/langues_regionales.pdf) une version archivée de la page.

Answer (score 7):

La base de donnée de l'[Ethnologue](http://www.ethnologue.org) donne 25 langues pour la [France](http://www.ethnologue.org/show_country.asp?name=FR) dont 2 éteintes et 2 langues des signes. Le breton est une langue à part du français (c'est une lange celtique et le français une langue romane). Le gallo cité par Laure y est considéré comme un dialecte du français.

On y trouve aussi une rapide [introduction aux problèmes posés par l'identification des langues](http://www.ethnologue.org/ethno_docs/introduction.asp#language_id).

Answer (score 4):

La [base de l'Unesco sur les langues du monde](http://www.unesco.org/languages-atlas/index.php) propose une carte interactive qui pourrait vous intéresser.

Concernant le partage entre dialectes et langues, l'exemple de l'occitan comme construction linguistique et politique (une langue pour la moitié de la France, c'est un moyen de se poser en alternative au français) est toujours sujet à controverses. En particulier, le statut du gascon et du béarnais vis-à-vis de l'occitan standard languedocien pose d'intéressantes questions: un État souverain (le Béarn) a-t-il pu avoir pour langue un dialecte ? [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gascon#Un_dialecte_ou_une_langue_sp.C3.A9cifique_.3F) présente rapidement le problème.

La [thèse (*Situation sociolinguistique et écriture du gascon aujourd'hui*, en ligne, 2005)](http://www.languegasconne.com/bearn-et-gascogne/la-langue-bearnaise-et-gasconne/index.html) et les articles de Jean Lafitte présentent les arguments des uns et des autres, mais dans une optique “sociolinguistique” évidemment orientée; en tout cas est-ce un bon début pour aller voir ensuite d'autres sources.

[Un numéro de 2012 (en ligne) de *Modèles linguistiques*](http://ml.revues.org/201) est également consacré aux langues régionales de Béarn et de Gascogne.

Comment: Eriger le languedocien en "standard" de l'occitan pose aussi question. Une des caractéristiques de la langue d'oc est sa variabilité. Je connais beaucoup d'anciens pour qui le parler de [Catinou et Jacouti](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Mouly) est bien plus "standard" que la version urbaine qu'on entend dans le métro de Toulouse.